# Records are filtered one-by-one in FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter

Tags: spring-kafka

I just realized that in spring-kafka the messagefiltering for batchlisteners are executed one after the other. (see FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter, version 2.7.4)

```
    @Override
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> consumerRecords, @Nullable Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
            Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        Iterator<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> iterator = consumerRecords.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (filter(iterator.next())) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
...
}
```

since in my filter implementation I need to make a lookup on our database the whole processing slows down.
Is there a way to overrule this behaviour in such a way that I need to lookup the database only once for the whole batch?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box; you would have to do the filtering in your batch listener instead.

Comment: Would be nice if this could be fixed in future versions

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1938